# How do I create a table the same time as other tables that pulls totals from each?

Tags: sql, sql-server

For class I'm creating a database that keeps track of my finances. I have a table for each type of item I purchase. For example `Rent`, `Food`, `Hygiene`, `Entertainment`,etc... I also have a table called `Register` that I want to display the monthly total for each item. The column names for the totals in the tables are as follows: `MonthlyRentTotal`, `MonthlyFoodTotal`, etc... 
I want the `Register` table to pull the total from each Table so I don't have to enter them twice. Any Ideas on how I can do that? I don't want to create a view either. I want it to be an actual table. I'm not even sure if this is possible.

Comment: Having different tables for each type of purchase seems like the flaw here. You should have 1 table for purchases with a category/type column. Having a different table for every type of purchase isn't going to scale and will require significant changes to your code **every** time a new type is added. Rent, I can *maybe* see as a different table, depending on the design. Every else, Food, Hygiene, entertainment are all physical item purchases, where as rent is a service. Therefore, depending on requirement, you might have 2 tables for services and purchases; but not enough detail to know.

Comment: Tables do not "pull" from other tables. Queries do that. I suggest you step back and think about your approach. Your class (and its purpose) should be considered here - is it database design? If not, have you studied db design at all? What you describe can be done but it will require code and it is not a typical approach. Maybe you should look at the sample MS databases like AdventureWorks or World Wide Importers to get some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that Rent, Food, Hygiene, Entertainment have same column type.

```
INSERT INTO Register
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT SUM(a.rent_value) AS value,
          'monthlyrent' AS TYPE
   FROM Rent a
   UNION SELECT SUM(b.food_value) AS value,
                'monthlyfood' AS TYPE
   FROM Food b) d pivot(max(value)
                        FOR TYPE IN (monthlyrent, monthlyfood)) piv;
```

Data was pivoted in order to be inserted into Register table.

[image]

You can put this query in a stored procedure or simply run it manually. If you want to have updated data in the Register table I suggest to :

- Create a stored procedure using a TRUNCATE for Register table followed by the above query
- Create an SQL Job and schedule the run of the stored procedure anytime you need.

Hope this helps. Let me know if you need additional details.

Answer (score 0):

You should only separate the items into separate tables if there is a compelling reason.  For the items you describe, I see no compelling reason.

I would imagine a data structure like this:

- `itemCategories` -- contains the list of categories you care about, such as "food", "hygiene", and so on.
- `Purchases` -- contains each purchase, with columns like `purchaseDate`, `location`, `itemCategory`, `description`, and so on.

You may want additional tables for other entities, such as "location".

What you are calling a `Register` table would then simply be a query or view on `Purchases`.

Comment: I need 8 tables and this is a term project. That's the only reason I have the tables as they are.

Comment: @DanielJaeger . . . That ranks among the worse reasons I can imagine to break data up into tables.  You need to think of a somewhat more complicated data model for your project.